# Is it possible reference to collection in another database in my Mongoose schema?

Tags: mongoose, nestjs, mongoose-schema

I have **multiple databases** .The first database is the reference and other database collections must reference to the first database.

Can I do this using  **nestjs(mongoose)**? If the answer is yes how should I do this?

My mongoose version is 7.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Create a connection for the second database in your module file (e.g., app.module.ts)

```
 @Module({
  imports: [
    // Connection to the first database
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/first-database'),
    // Connection to the second database
    MongooseModule.forRoot('mongodb://localhost/second-database', {
      name: 'second-connection', // Give a name to the connection
    }),
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

In the schema definition of the second collection, use the *ref* property to reference the collection from the first database.

```
@Schema({ collection: 'second-collection', _id: false, timestamps: true })
export class SecondCollection {
  @Prop({ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'FirstCollection', required: true })
  firstCollectionRef: string;
}
```

Use it in your service controller.

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(
    @InjectModel(SecondCollection.name, 'second-connection')
    private readonly secondCollectionModel: Model<SecondCollection>,
  ) {}
}
```

Holp it helps!

Comment: Thanks. I did what you said, but I've got this error:
` Schema hasn't been registered for model 'FirstCollection' `.